# How I can show "Local Area Connection" properties dialog

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, networking, com

I should show the "Local Area Connection" properties dialog (it is the dialog which has two tabs Networking and Sharing) from my program.

How I can do it?

Now I use this function:

```
void ShowPropertiesDialog(INetConnection * pConn)
{ 
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CLSID clsid;

CComPtr<INetCfg> pNetCfg;

if (SUCCEEDED(pConn->GetUiObjectClassId(&clsid)))
{
    CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnk;
    if(SUCCEEDED(pUnk.CoCreateInstance(clsid)))
    {
        CComPtr<INetConnectionPropertyUi> pNetConnectionPropertyUi;
        hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_INetConnectionPropertyUi, (void**)&pNetConnectionPropertyUi);
        hr = pNetConnectionPropertyUi->SetConnection(pConn);

        hr = pNetCfg.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CNetCfg);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            CComPtr<INetCfgLock> pNetCfgLock;
            hr = pNetCfg->QueryInterface(IID_INetCfgLock, (void**)&pNetCfgLock);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pNetCfgLock->AcquireWriteLock(15000, TEXT("MY CLIENT"), NULL);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pNetCfg->Initialize(NULL);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        CComPtr<INetCfgComponent> pTcpIp;
                        if (SUCCEEDED(pNetCfg->FindComponent(NETCFG_TRANS_CID_MS_TCPIP, &pTcpIp)))
                        {
                            hr = pTcpIp->RaisePropertyUi(GetConsoleWindow(), NCRP_SHOW_PROPERTY_UI, pNetConnectionPropertyUi);
                        }

                        pNetCfg->Uninitialize();
                    }

                    pNetCfgLock->ReleaseWriteLock();
                }
            }
            pNetCfg.Release();
        }
    }
}
}
```

use:

```
hr = pENConnection->Next(1, &pConn, &ulCount); 
....
hr = pConn->GetProperties(&pProps);
if (pProps->MediaType == NCM_LAN)
{
    ShowPropertiesDialog(pConn);
}
```

but `RaisePropertyUi` always returned `E_NOINTERFACE` :(

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done anything with this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547895(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes but what I should pass in 3 param?

Comment: I recommend editing the question to include what you know, what you've tried, and specifically where you're stuck.  You'll get more answers if you're not asking people to start from the very beginning.

Comment: check this sample code out: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/howto-show-tcp-ip-properties-using-inetcfgcomponent-raisepropertyui-help-26991332.html